# why does numpy int64 not work with timedelta64

Tags: python, numpy

I was wondering why I get the below error when using `numpy.int64` with `numpy.timedelta64`

> ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta

**For example:**

```
In [10]: np.timedelta64(np.int64(2),'D')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-06ccd44f066c> in <module>()
----> 1 np.timedelta64(np.int64(2),'D')

ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta
```

**The reason for my question:** I am using `scipy.stats.mode` and pass the result into `numpy.timedelta64` in the interim I do the below `int` as a fix but interested to find out why such behaviour occurs:

```
from scipy.stats import mode
import nump as np
np.timedelta64(int(mode([2,2,3,4,1,1,5,5])[0][0]),'D')

Out[15]: numpy.timedelta64(1,'D')
```

**Might be a version issue ?**

numpy version = 1.10.4

python version = 2.7.11 (64 bit)

Comment: I just checked your code with `python 2.7.12` with `numpy 1.14.5` and `python 3.7`, both work so yes it seem like a version issue

Comment: See if `np.int32` works for your versions: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4440

Comment: Interesting! Yeah `np.int32` works without an error, looks like you right likely version issue, will try a more recent `numpy`